# Framesets in dalekjs

Tags: dalekjs

How can I access a frameset using dalekjs? There is an Action "toFrame" but it seems it works only for iFrames.

Example:

```
<frameset rows="60,*" onload="frames['content'].location.href='xxx'"  frameborder="0" framespacing="0" >      
  <frame name="menu"    src="yyy" frameborder="0" noresize scrolling="no" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" />
  <frame name="content" src="" frameborder="0" noresize/>
</frameset>
```

I wanna access the frame name "menu". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, as Dalek has been created in the year of 2013, it does not support `<frameset>`, Dalek only aims to support HTML5 compliant HTML & the `<frameset>` tag is gone in HTML5.

Comment: Ohh too bad :( is there any workaround i could use to solve this problem? all my tests are inside the menu and content frames, but i can't access them, and dalekjs is the better testing tool i've came across so far.

Comment: I'm afraid no :/
I can recommend you WD.js (https://github.com/admc/wd), the entry barrier is a bit higher than with Dalek only, but it has the ability you're looking for (as far as I know).

If you have problems setting up Selenium locally, try this node module https://www.npmjs.org/package/selenium-standalone (it helps with that a lot).

Last & least, check this video, it helps get you started with WD.js - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dzplh1tAwIg

Sorry that I can't help you getting this to work with Dalek, but fortunately this is not a common scenario nowadays.